# How to sort inner tables by value?

Tags: lua, lua-table, computercraft

So, as the title says, I would like to sort a table of tables in Lua.
One such example nested table is below.

```
tabl = {2.0={amount=281.0, meta=0.0, displayName=Dirt, name=minecraft:dirt}, 3.0={amount=190103.0, meta=0.0, displayName=Cobblestone, name=minecraft:cobblestone}, ...}
```

I would like to go through and return a table of the top ten `tabl[*]['amount']` listed with their respective `tabl[*]['displayName']` * being a wildcard for `tabl[1.0]` through `tabl[max.0]`

A finished table should look something like:

```
sorted = {1={displayName=Cobblestone, amount=190103}, 2={displayName=Dirt, amount=281}, ...}
```

I hope this makes sense to all out there.

Link to full nested table: [Full Piece](http://pastebin.com/YXw3NQqx)
FYI: I am not in control of how the table is returned to me; I got them from the function `listItems()` in [this](http://peripheralsplusplus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peripherals/me_bridge/) API.

Comment: You need to put numbers in [ ] to have correct syntax.
sorted = {
  [1]={displayName=Cobblestone, amount=190103},
  [2]={displayName=Dirt, amount=281}
  }
Even though natural number indices are the default, but just in case you need to specify elements in a different order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I worked at it for a while, and thanks to community answers I came up with this piece:

```
bridge = peripheral.wrap("left")
items = bridge.listItems()

sorted = {}

for i, last in next, items do
  sorted[i] = {}
  sorted[i]["displayName"] = items[i]["displayName"]
  sorted[i]["amount"] = items[i]["amount"]
end

table.sort(sorted, function(a,b) return a.amount > b.amount end)

for i = 1, 10 do
  print(i .. ": " .. sorted[i].displayName .. ": " .. sorted[i].amount)
end
```

It returned the top 10 inventories:

```
1: Cobblestone: 202924
2: Gunpowder: 1382
3: Flint: 1375
4: Oak Sapling: 1099
5: Arrow: 966
6: Bone Meal: 946
7: Sky Stone Dust: 808
8: Certus Quartz Dust: 726
9: Rotten Flesh: 627
10: Coal: 618
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your *arrays* **aren't *syntactically correct***. It should be more like:

```
local people = {
    {Name="Alice",Score=10},
    {Name="Bob",Score=3},
    {Name="Charlie",Score=17}
}
```

Secondly, the `table.sort` function should do the job. In my particular example it would look *like* this:

```
table.sort(people, function(a,b) return a.Score > b.Score end)
```

And finally, to get the top `N` just *iterate*:

```
for i = 1,N do
    print(people[i].Name, people[i].Score)
end
```

Comment: a comma is missing in line 3. also you should make sure that N does not exceed #people. Otherwise you"ll get an error for indexing nil values.

Comment: @Piglet Fixed comma, N exceeding #people would be a mistake on his end, I simply explained how to do it.

Comment: @warspyking But it could be corrected like so: for i = 1,N <= #people and N or #people do

Comment: @tony While true, he should never run into the problem in the first place. Why run extra code, for the price of inefficiency?

Comment: @warspyking I'm sorry I should have mentioned that I have no control over the original piece, it is returned by an external api.